# long long int arithmetics

Tags: c, long-long

I have the following in C:

```
long long int a;
long long int b;
long long int c;
long long int d=a*b/c;
```

However, I want 'd' to be double. Is there a way I can multiply, divide long long int and get a double as an answer keeping up to 3 decimals as precision?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast (at least) one of the `long long int`s to `double`

```
double d = a * (double)b / c;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not multiplying and dividing `long long`s anymore (although obviously the best approach). And when casting just `c`, there is a possible integer overflow in `a * b`.

Answer (score 1):

if your numbers aren't going to overflow if you do this, you can multiple everything by 1000.  Also, make sure you Always multiply things before dividing by things.  You can convert to a double,  but it will then potentially lose information.

Answer (score 0):

Since C expressions, including subexpressions, are usually evaluated without regard to the context in which they appear, the subexpression `a*b/c` will be evaluated using integer arithmetic, which means truncating division.

If you want to perform floating-point arithmetic on integer values, you need to convert them to a floating-point type.  This should work in your case:

```
long long int a;
long long int b;
long long int c;
/* Assign values to a, b, and c (!) */
double d = (double)a * b / c;
```

Note that converting just the first operand is enough to cause both the multiplication and the division to be done in type `double`.

Answer (score -1):

Say `double d = double(a) * double(b) / double(c);` to get a floating point result. (You actually only need *one* element to be a `double` to have everything promoted, but why not be explicit.) You get the usual precision of the double-precision floating point (i.e. you don't get to pick a "precision level").

Are you sure you need **floating** point arithmetic (i.e. does your problem require multiple scales)? Maybe fixed-point arithmetic is more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: In my calculation I might get 5.115 where 115 is crucial however any number greater than 100 I dont care about the decimals I get.
Do you suggest any other way of doing it?

Comment: I thought I just did - **fixed** point arithmetic. See @Keith's answer.